# Prototype. Ajax request parameters as nested json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, prototype

I want to send request with special parameters like in example listed below. But unfortunately this script sends only id. How can i transfer nested JSON?

```
new Ajax.Request("/specials/update_users_specials", {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {
        id: '1',
        data: {
            data_one: '2',
            data_two: '3'
        }
    },
    onSuccess:function(){}
});
```

UPD.
I've tried

```
var parameters = {}; 
$A(rows).each(function(d){ 
    parameters[d.dataset.userId] = d.value; 
}); 
params={}; 
params['data']=parameters; 
params['part']=45;
```

don't work.
I've tried

```
var parameters_json = eval("(" +JSON.stringify(params) + ")");
```

don't work.
And now i've tried

```
$H({ id: '1', data: { data_one: '2', data_two: '3' } })
```

The same result.

UPD.

I'm using rails and my solution would:

```
var parameters = {}; 
$A(rows).each(function(d){ 
    parameters['users[' + d.dataset.userId + ']'] = d.value; 
}); 
parameters['part_id']=id;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the manual, http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options:

> parameters    ''  The parameters for the request, which will be encoded into the URL for a 'get' method, or into the request body for the other methods. This can be provided either as a URL-encoded string or as any [Hash](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/hash)-compatible object (basically anything), with properties representing parameters."

And regarding Hash, http://www.prototypejs.org/api/hash:

> There are two ways to construct a Hash instance: the first is regular JavaScript object instantiation with the new keyword, and the second is using the [$H](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-h) function. Passing a plain JavaScript object or a Hash to any of them would clone it, keeping your original object intact.

So, create a Hash out of the JSON and you should be good.

**UPDATE**

Even more from their page (it was a long time ago since I used prototype myself) http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax

```js
new Ajax.Request('/some_url', {
    method: 'get',
    parameters: {company: 'example', limit: 12}
});
```

> Parameters are passed in as a hash (preferred) or a string of key-value pairs separated by ampersands (like company=example&limit=12).

Therefor it does not understand a multidimensional hash, just key-value pairs.

However, I did find [this snippet of code at Google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/prototype-scriptaculous/G8-10cG_E4k/_499MGaUT7IJ) that might help you out.